# Is CiviEngage a core part of CiviCRM now?

Tags: drupal, wordpress, civicampaign

I'm a new Civi user with the intent of using CiviCRM for political campaigns. I keep coming across dated articles talking about CiviCampaign and how it's functionality is extended by CiviEngage, which is only available on Drupal. However, I did not find CiviEngage in the available public modules list.

I am testing CiviCRM on both WordPress and Drupal, and I noticed that Drupal lists CiviEngage as an activated module by default, however I find no equivalent in WordPress. Is the functionality provided in CiviEngage now a core part of CiviCRM on all available platforms, or is this still specific to CiviCRM on Drupal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CiviEngage, *at the moment*, is a Drupal module that currently ships with the official CiviCRM Drupal release (see https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/tree/7.x-master/modules/civicrm_engage, which ends up installed in sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/civicrm_engage). That means you won't find it on drupal.org or any other drupal module site and you will only see it in your CiviCRM installation as an available module if you are running CiviCRM on Drupal.

Having said that... plans are underway to first split the module out of CiviCRM and onto drupal.org so it can be downloaded and installed like any other third party drupal module and eventually be converted into an extensions so it can be used by anyone.

More information is available in this issue:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16671

Comment: Thanks for the information. Are there any particular features in CiviEngage that are dependent upon Drupal specifically? I do a bit of WordPress development and wouldn't mind helping in getting this module democratized.

Comment: Awesome @JoeJordan! AFAIK the only reason it's a drupal module is the legacy issue that extensions for Civi didn't exist at the time it was written. Try creating a new extension with Civix, copying the code over from the module, and see how far you get :)

Comment: NB as far as I know the main things in CiviEngage are
1) an initial config - it adds a bunch of custom groups & fields that PTP has developed as a useful set for community-organising type organisations
2) it has some extensions to CiviReport.walklists etc

Probably these would wind up being separate extensions in the end

Comment: I would like to see the CiviCRM core Activity field for Engagement Index which originated in some CiviEngage work (if I'm not mistaken) be moved to an extension as well. (See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/xml/schema/Activity/Activity.xml#L437) There are many uses for Activities and custom Activity Types where this is not appropriate. It would be better to be able to turn it on for specific Activity types than to have to hide it.