# Is CiviEngage available with Backdrop CMS?

Tags: civicampaign, backdrop

CiviEngage is a Drupal module. Since Backdrop CMS is a fork of Drupal, porting modules is rather straightforward, from what I understand. Is CiviEngage available for Backdrop CMS yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the long-term plan is to turn CiviEngage into an extension for CiviCRM (see [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/is-civiengage-a-core-part-of-civicrm-now) and [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16671)) and deprecate the module. I don't see much recent action on that front, so you might be right that a simple port to BackdropCMS from the Drupal7 module would be the quickest way to start using it in the meantime. In short:

- If you are able to help convert to a native CiviCRM extension (by coding or sponsoring), that
  would be a great place to start.
- If you can't do that but can do the module port to Backdrop CMS, that should be quite painless (he says without having looked at the code directly).
- Beyond those, you could also submit a [module port request for Backdrop CMS here](https://github.com/backdrop-ops/contrib/issues). (I'm guessing it won't get into CiviCRM's core Backdrop implementation since the plan is to phase that into an extension, but it could be ported and hosted on BackdropCMS's contrib section in the meantime until such an extension exists).

**UPDATE:** It seems that CiviEngage may be ported to Backdrop and included in the Backdrop version of CiviCRM, unbeknownst to me. I have not tested it but give it a shot. 
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/tree/1.x-master/modules/civicrm_engage

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful information, and I'd agree those are the best options available. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to contact the developers if you can't find anything on the CiviCRM Extension Repository.