# Do not see CIVIEngage in "Enable CiviCRM Components" to Enable

Tags: civicampaign, modules

I recently installed Drupal 9 & CiviCRM 5.42.1
In "Enable CiviCRM Components" I see other modules - CiviCase, Campaign, etc. but do not see CiviEngage, to enable.
As I understand, CiviEngage gets installed along with the Core, and all i need to do is to enable it.

Not sure if I missed anything in my installation steps.

regards,
--Sujit

Comment: Where did you see that it gets installed? That should maybe be removed. See https://civicrm.org/blog/jamie/civicrmengage-is-dead-long-live-civicrmengage

Comment: Oh Ok.  was going by CiviCRM docs. It says that CiviEngage is part of the core and gets installed automatically, and only need to enabled. But I understand, it may have been dis-continued. Thanks for sharing the blog link. I will use individual extensions for our need. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

that is because CiviEngage is not part of core CiviCRM, see this post:
[Is CiviEngage a core part of CiviCRM now?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/is-civiengage-a-core-part-of-civicrm-now)